# Undefined control sequence

Tags: latex

I am making my Master's Thesis with LaTeX, but I can't get the provided style to work. Specifically, I get the error 'Undefined control sequence' when using the function `makeformaltitlepages`, which is defined in `mscthesis.sty`. On the internet, the only answer I could find is the straightforward 'you probably made a typo', or 'you probably forgot to include the package', but I have reason to believe neither of those apply to me.

In the preamble, I set several variables using macros defined in the style file, such as my name and the company information of the company that provided the assignment. After the beginning of the document, the function `maketitlepages` is called from the style file, which creates several title pages matching the university style.

[edit]

After finding the solution, I now know where the error comes from. Below is a small style file and a small document that can be compiled to recreate the error. In a nutshell, I used `includegraphics` to include an image file whose filename contained a space.

example.sty:

```
\def\company#1{\gdef\@company{#1}}

\def\maketitlepages
{\begingroup
    \newpage
    \noindent
    \begin{center}
        \vskip 0em \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
        \vskip 1em {\Huge \@title \par}
        \vskip 1em \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt} \par \nobreak
        \vskip 4em {\large A DOCUMENT}
        \vskip 2em by
        \vskip 2em {\large \@author}
        \vfill
        \@company
    \end{center}
    \newpage
\endgroup}
```

document.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{example}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}

\author{Your name}

\company{
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{company logo.eps}\\
  A Company\\
  Addressline 1\\
  Addressline 2\\
  Country\\
  \url{www.acompany.com}
}

\title{Undefined control sequence}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitlepages
```

Comment: Where did you get `mscthesis.sty`?  I can't find it on CTAN or elsewhere.

Comment: It was provided by our department for computer science, but I found that the error was not in there. Instead, the error turned out to hide in the inclusion of a .ps picture, which I naïvely assumed to be perfectly correct. Apparently, it is an error to use the `includegraphics` command for a filename with a whitespace in it.

I'll rewrite the question, so it might give a hint to other people who also get this error because they somewhere make a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Can we see the relevant part of `mscthesis.sty`?  My (otherwise uninformed) guess is that's where the error is -- I suspect that when it defines `\makeformaltitlepages`, it uses that command.

Answer (score 1):

What we need is a complete example showing the problem (i.e. starting with \documentclass{...} and going through to \end{document}). Quite possibly one of your "gibberish lines" are important. (This is probably better answered somewhere like The LaTeX Community forums.)